# How to get value type from decltype a reference?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a template function as below:

```
template<typename T>
void do_something(T &c) {
  decltype(c[0]) tmp;
  //...
}
```

`T` can be an array or container. This declares tmp as a reference, but I want a value type and does not initialize it (so I don't want to do `auto tmp = c[0]`). How can I do this?

Comment: `std::remove_reference`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If its just a reference problem, you can use `std::remove_reference` in `<type_traits>`:

```
typename std::remove_reference<decltype(c[0])>::type tmp;
```

Comment: Fixed, a little typo :)

Comment: @stefan Make that `remove_reference_t` and you can drop your alias when C++1y is released (it'll ship with the StdLib then).

Comment: @dyp too much to type ;-)

Comment: Perhaps `template<typename T> T auto_(T); template<typename T> std::initializer_list<T> auto_(std::initializer_list<T>);` so you can write `decltype(auto_(c[0])) tmp;`

Comment: `std::decay` is also tempting, as it also strips cv (`const` and `volatile`) (which probably aren't what you want your local copy of data to be).  It does other stuff: if your `c` is an array-of-arrays, the expression will become legal (but `tmp` will be a pointer, not an array).